# jQuery plugin returning object

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have the following script for a jQuery plugin template, and I'm not sure whether the plugin should actually return an object like this: `return $.fn.Plugin;` or whether it is acceptable just to leave the definition like this: `$.fn.Plugin = Plugin;` The script (including chaining) appears to work without the 'return'.

My question is what would be the best practice for this situation? Any insight or advice would be much appreciated.

```
; (function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    "use strict";

    var Plugin = function (options) {

        this.fnPublicFunctionOne = function () {
            console.log('"called fnPublicFunctionOne plugin internal"');
            _fnPrivateFunction();
        };

        function _fnPrivateFunction() {
            console.log('"called _fnPrivateFunction plugin internal"');
        }

        this.each(function () {
            // Logic here to prevent multiple or incorrect instantiation with 'return;'
            $.extend(true, Plugin.options, options);    
            console.log('sId: ' + this.getAttribute('id'));
        });

        return this;
    };

    Plugin.options = {    
        option_one: 'default_option_one',
        option_two: 'default_option_two'    
    };

    $.fn.Plugin = Plugin;
    // Is this needed ?
    return $.fn.Plugin;

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: Read this: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#chaining and then this https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#using-the-each-method

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I have read it - but the basic pattern shown, as far as I understand it, is not the same as this pattern. This pattern (without the return) also allows chaining.

Comment: Ah yes, my bad, the actual plugin itself already does `return this` - you're just self initiating it in an IIFE.  In which case, where does the return `$.fn.Plugin` get used?  No where.  It's the return of this call `(function () {})(jQuery, window, document);`, which you're not using.  So has no effect.

Comment: Thank you - that explains a lot (if I understand you correctly) - there is no need to "return $.fn.Plugin;" because the call to the plugin self-initiates an IIFE, and that is sufficient.

Comment: Where will `fnPublicFunctionOne` ever be visible?

Comment: @Tomalak var plugin_item = $('#element').Plugin().addClass('test-class'); plugin_item.fnPublicFunctionOne(); seems to work

Comment: Uhh... I don't think so, becaue `$('#element').Plugin()` returns a jQuery object (because `Plugin` returns `this`, which is a jQuery object by definition). And on a jQuery object, `fnPublicFunctionOne` would not exist, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @Tomalak I really do wish I understood more about this at a deeper level to give a solid reason, but it does seem to work.

Comment: Ahh, I see it now. You are adding a function to `this` inside the Plugin, where `this` is a jQuery instance. Subsequently that function is available on that particular jQuery instance. This is unclean, don't do that. For example, it will fail here: `plugin_item = $('#element').Plugin().find('.foo')` because `jQuery#find` will return a new jQuery instance.

Comment: @Tomalak Unclean sounds bad heh. Is this is "modify the plugin" or a "scrap the pattern" moment? Access to Public functions, but keeping Private functions private, was one key thing I was trying to achieve.

Comment: It's a modify the plugin moment. Many jQuery plugins have the concept of an "instance" (all the jQuery UI widgets do, jQuery TableSorter does, and many others). Look how they solve the problem of keeping their instance object separate from the jQuery object. An easy way would be to store the instance in jQuery `.data()`. When `.plugin()` (you really should use lowercase for everything that's not a constructor) is called on an element, you can decide whether a new instance must be constructed or the current one can be accessed. Then `.plugin('publicMethodName', arguments)` becomes possible.

Comment: The pinch here is that the jQuery pattern (fluid interface a.k.a. method chaining) requires you to return a jQuery object from your plugin. A few jQuery functions break the pattern, like `.text()`, which returns a string and therefore does not support chaining, but in general you shouldn't. This means `.plugin()` cannot return a plugin instance with public methods and properties. And THIS means, `.plugin(some, arguments)` is your interface. Most plugins have settled on translating `some, arguments` into an internal method call on the respective instance.

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you sincerely for your comments - they really do add significant insight. I will do more research based on what you have said. Weird one though: var plugin_item = $('#element').Plugin().find('.element-class');
console.log('plugin_item ' + plugin_item.first().attr('id')); seems to work. Sheesh. I really do need to understand this more.

Comment: A jQuery instance is effectively a wrapper around a list of DOM nodes. It's an array on steroids, really. When you chain a few jQuery methods (in fact, each and every one of them is a plugin), they work on it and then decide whether they want to return the same instance (`return this;`) or a new one (`return $("something else")`). The same instance will carry all modifications you've made to it. The new one will be, well, new. Some jQuery functions do the one thing, some the other. Therefore, modifying the jQuery instance is not stable.

Comment: Try it: `var $a = $("div"); $a.foo = "FOO"; var $b = $a.find("span"); console.log($a === $b, $a.foo, $b.foo);` logs `false FOO undefined`, which means `$a` is not identical to `$b` and the modification to `$a` has not carried over to `$b` either. `$a === $a.css('color', 'red')` would return `true` though, because in contrast to `.find()`, `.css()` does not return a new instance, but the same one.